# djstripe customer subscription deletion webhook event not working properly

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have configured the djstripe webhook subscription deletion webhook to save subscriptions with cancel status.

```
from djstripe import webhooks
import djstripe.model

@webhooks.handler("customer.subscription.deleted")
def subscription_deletion_handler(event, **kwargs):
    data = event.data.get("object", {})
    djstripe_subs_status = data.get('status')
    djstripe_subs_id = data.get('id')

    djstripe_subscription = djstripe.models.Subscription.objects.get(id=djstripe_subs_id)
    djstripe_subscription.status = djstripe_subs_status
    djstripe_subscription.save()
```

But while getting subscription object it throws
`djstripe.models.billing.subscription.DoesNotExist` exception and automatically deleted object from database. Please correct me and let me know if there is any issue in the above code.